# extract hour from date with timezone property in Python

Tags: python

```
    timestamp   utc_time             country    score   timezone                local_time
1   1631865749  2021-09-17 08:02:29 Germany       10    Europe/Berlin   2021-09-17 10:02:29+02:00
```

I would like to extract the hour form the "local_time" column, which data type is currently 'object'.

```
from datetime import datetime as dt
df_with_local_time['hour_of_day']=df_with_local_time['local_time'].dt.hour
```

does not work, unless I specify UTC=True.
However, I want to do the analysis based on the local time, not based on UTC time.

Expected result:

```
timestamp   utc_time             score  timezone                local_time        hour
1631865749  2021-09-17 08:02:29   10    Europe/Berlin   2021-09-17 10:02:29+02:00 10
```

Comment: can't you convert to string and split on space and get last element?

Answer (score 0):

You can try converting the column type to datetime first. Try:

```
df_with_local_time['local_time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_with_local_time['local_time'])
```

Notice that now it is not a object-type, which you can verify like this:

```
df_with_local_time.info()
```

> <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'> RangeIndex: 1 entries, 0 to 0
> Data columns (total 1 columns):  #   Column  Non-Null Count  Dtype
>
> ---  ------  --------------  -----                                  0   date    1 non-null      datetime64[ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120)] dtypes:
> datetime64ns, pytz.FixedOffset(120) memory usage: 136.0 bytes

and then extract the hour pretty much the same way you indicated:

```
int(df_with_local_time['local_time'].dt.hour)
```

> 10

Comment: it is exactly the method I described above, it doesn't work because:

ValueError: Tz-aware datetime.datetime cannot be converted to datetime64 unless utc=True